# Angular need page refresh to load new view

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angular-routing

I am trying to develope an app using angular.js and phonegap. My problem is that I have set everything good in my router, but still new views are not loading, so in order to change the view after the route is changed you need to refresh.

Here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

        <!-- Use the .min version of bootstrap files in production -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Angular PhoneGap Sample</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- The following tag is in place of ng-view to use the angular mobile view navigation framework
            https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav
        -->
        <mobile-view/>

        <!-- Comment out the following 2 lines to test on the browser-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/index.js"></script>

        <!-- In production use min versions -->
        <script src="lib/jx.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-mobile.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/mobile-nav.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--         // <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        // <script src="lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
        // <script src="lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script> -->

        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/main/mainController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/about/aboutController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/about/playController.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the app.js

```
'use strict';

function jsonp_callback(data) {
    // returning from async callbacks is (generally) meaningless
    console.log(data.found);
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ajoslin.mobile-navigate', 'ngMobile']);

myApp.config(function ($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
})  
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/play', {
      templateUrl: 'app/play/play.html',
      controller: 'PlayCtrl'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/options', {
      templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);

myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location){
    // $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection){
    //     if(rejection === 'not-authorized'){
    //         $location.path('/');
    //     }
    //     if(rejection == 'authorized'){
    //         $location.path('/home');
    //     }
    // });
    var history = [];

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        history.push($location.$$path);
    });
    $rootScope.history = history;
});
```

And I tried to change route both with a hyperlink `href="#/play" and within the controller`$location.path('/play');` but nothing works ;/

Comment: did you try to use ng-view instead of mobile-view and  try the code with simple angular

Comment: yes, still not working. I recon the problem might be in ngRoute, as I am not including it, but when I do and I inject it in the app dependecies I get this error: "Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- $navigate "

Comment: you have to include route file otherwise it will not work

Comment: also try to include angular-santize.js and then it should work

Comment: angular-sanitize.js throws and error, undefined is not a function ;/

Comment: It was a problem with the version, now I got ngRoute, angular-sanitize and still, the problem is like before, when I go to a new route it only adds content to the view but the old content stays ;//

Comment: where is ngRoute injector in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, nothing will work until you inject ngRoute. You have to add that file too in Index.html.

angular-route.js is now separate file. You manually have to inject that file in order to run your defined routes.

One more thing with 'a' html link tag you have to write href="#play"...

I'm not sure about mobile-view. so use  ng-view  if it doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks, the hrefs were the problem but now there is no history, when I press back nothing happens ;/

Comment: nope, ngRoute is something I added anyways but it was still not working...at the end I used this service which I will post as another answer below in order for the code to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

At the end I was able to get it running with angular-mobile, ngRoute, and no hrefs. Instead of them I used this function on ng-click:

```
$scope.slidePage = function (path,type) {
    navSvc.slidePage(path,type);
};
```

with this service, of course:

```
myApp.factory('navSvc', function($navigate) {

   return {
        slidePage: function (path,type) {
            $navigate.go(path,type);
        },
        back: function () {
            $navigate.back();
        }
    }
});
```